# navbar goes underneath the content on the page when the menu opens

Tags: html, css

i have this table on my page and the css for navbar is given below
the problem is that when the menu falls from navbar its goes right underneath the table. obviously i want it to stay on top of every on the page.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th class="info">o</th>
            <th class="info">Td</th>
            <th class="info">jdj</th>
            <th class="info">jd</th>
            <th class="info">js</th>
            </tr>
            <script type="text/javascript">

//further fetch data using javascript
The css and jquery for navbar:

<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
}
.logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 123;
    padding: 10px;
    font: 18px verdana;
    color: #97455f;
    float: left;
    width: auto
}
.logo a {
    color: #97455f;
}
nav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #head-mobile {
    border: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0
}
#cssmenu #head-mobile {
    display: none
}
#cssmenu {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #333
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {

display:inline-block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
    color: #fff
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active,
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub.active:hover {
    background: #97455f!important;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background .3s ease;
    transition: background .3s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
    padding-right: 30px
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 23px;
    height: 0
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    background: #333;
    transition: all .25s ease
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover {} #cssmenu li:hover > ul {
    left: auto
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: 35px
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    margin-left: 100%;
    top: 0
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
    padding: 11px 15px;
    width: 170px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 400;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
    border-bottom: 0
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 11px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #ddd;
    content: ''
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 14px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #ddd;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
    top: 17px;
    height: 0
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover {
    background: #363636;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
    border-left: 1px solid #333
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a {
    border-top: 1px solid #333
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .logo {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 46px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        float: none
    }
    .logo2 {
        display: none
    }
    nav {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #cssmenu {
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;

    }
    #cssmenu ul {
        width: 100%;
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu ul li {
        width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid #444
    }
    #cssmenu ul li:hover {
        background: #363636;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li,
    #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
        height: auto
    }
    #cssmenu ul li a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 0
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li {
        float: none
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        padding-left: 25px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
        background: #333!important;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
        background: #363636!important
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
        padding-left: 35px
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        color: #ddd;
        background: none
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
        color: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul,
    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
    #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
    #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu #head-mobile {
        display: block;
        padding: 23px;
        color: #ddd;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700
    }
    .button {
        width: 55px;
        height: 46px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 12399994;
    }
    .button:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 20px;
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        width: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
        content: ''
    }
    .button:before {
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
        transition: all .3s ease;
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        right: 20px;
        display: block;
        height: 2px;
        width: 20px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    .button.menu-opened:after {
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
        transition: all .3s ease;
        top: 23px;
        border: 0;
        height: 2px;
        width: 19px;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg)
    }
    .button.menu-opened:before {
        top: 23px;
        background: #fff;
        width: 19px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg)
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        border-left: 1px solid #444;
        height: 46px;
        width: 46px;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
        background: #262626
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
        height: 34px;
        width: 34px
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 22px;
        right: 19px;
        width: 8px;
        height: 2px;
        display: block;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
        top: 15px;
        right: 13px
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
        background: #fff
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 19px;
        right: 22px;
        display: block;
        width: 2px;
        height: 8px;
        background: #ddd;
        content: ''
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
        top: 12px;
        right: 16px
    }
    #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
        display: none
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a {
        border-left: none
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,
    #cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a {
        border-top: none
    }

}
    #cssmenu > ul {float:right;}
    #cssmenu ul ul a {text-align: left;}
</style>
```

jquery is as follows:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
     var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
       format: "dropdown",
       sticky: false
     }, options);
     return this.each(function() {
       $(this).find(".button").on('click', function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
         var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
         if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
           mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
         }
         else {
           mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
           if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
             mainmenu.find('ul').show();
           }
         }
       });
       cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
    multiTg = function() {
         cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
         cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
           $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
           if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
             $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
           }
           else {
             $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
           }
         });
       };
       if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
       else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
       if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
    resizeFix = function() {
      var mediasize = 1000;
         if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
           cssmenu.find('ul').show();
         }
         if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
           cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
         }
       };
       resizeFix();
       return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
     });
      };
    })(jQuery);

    (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
       format: "multitoggle"
    });
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

section from navbar:

```
<li ><a href="#">some</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#>some</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">some</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

i cant seem to locate where i am going wrong with this. any help would be very much appreciated.i wish that when the menu falls down the content remains on top of everything but instead it goes right underneath the table that i have on my page. i have spent hours looking for what i am doing wrong but i can overlook even smallest of my mistakes. kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% following how your code is working, but making sure the z-index of the navbar is greater than the z-index of the table (if there is one) should work.